# Logback rollover not happening

Tags: java, logging, logback

I have created a `logback.xml` file but the rollover is not happening. It creates the `mylog.log` file but even if the size crosses 2KB the rollover doesn't happen and it keeps appending to the original `mylog.log` file. The same is happening when I use the `FILE1` appender which uses `FixedWindowRolling` Policy which I have commented. I m really stuck and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true" scan="true">

<!-- Send debug messages to System.out -->
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- By default, encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder -->
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<file>C:/log/mylog.log</file>
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
<!-- rollover daily -->
  <fileNamePattern>C:/log/mylog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.txt</fileNamePattern>
   <!-- each file should be at most 100MB, keep 60 days worth of history, but at most 20GB -->
   <maxFileSize>2KB</maxFileSize>    
   <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
   <totalSizeCap>2MB</totalSizeCap>
</rollingPolicy>
<encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!--
<appender name="FILE1" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>C:/log/jcg.log</file>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <FileNamePattern>c:/log/jcg.%i.log.zip</FileNamePattern>
        <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
        <MaxIndex>2</MaxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <MaxFileSize>2KB</MaxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>

</appender> -->

<logger name="com.tcs" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</logger>

<!-- By default, the level of the root level is set to DEBUG -->
<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to the appender element

```
<prudent>false</prudent>
```

Comment: didn't work,rollover not happening, it keeps appending to the same file even when mylog.log file crosses the 2kb mark.